Enabling DTC-02U [Digi Touch Controller] on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to get the touchscreen working on an IGT G20 slot machine. However, the touchscreen gets no response. I found the model of touchscreen controller using this command:
udevadm info --export-db | awk '/Touch/' RS=
This gives the path the touchscreen is routed too as well:
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 
N: bus/usb/001/003
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/003
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: PRODUCT=161c/2/230
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: BUSNUM=001
E: DEVNUM=003
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=2
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=2234312
E: ID_VENDOR=Digitech_Systems
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Digitech\x20\x20\x20Systems
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=161c
E: ID_MODEL=DigitechSys
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=DigitechSys
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0002
E: ID_REVISION=0230
E: ID_SERIAL=Digitech_Systems_DigitechSys
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Digitech Systems
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=DTC-02U [Digi Touch Controller]
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4
E: TAGS=:seat:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:

I went into the kernel configuration to try to enable the device driver using:
cd /usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40/
sudo make menuconfig
In the config menu I went to "Device Drivers"--->"Input device support"--->"Touchscreens" then enabled the JASTEC/DIGITECH driver.
JASTEC/DIGITECH Driver
Then I made sure all the dependencies were enabled as well and saved and exited.
Then I used the make command to start the build:
sudo make
And got this error message:
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop. 
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:249: archheaders] Error 2 
make: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2

I then tried this command:
sudo make -d -j$(nproc)
Which ran the command but still showed those same error messages from above.
Now this is the point where I'm stuck, not sure if I went down the wrong rabbit whole and if there's another way to get the touchscreen working or if I just need to get those errors dealt with.

Is the device quite recent? Then try 24.04. It would have better support for a recent touchscreen device.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Its from 2011 so its not really recent.
